# No Desktop or Wrong Desktop depending on HDMI Connection

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hdmi, desktop

When using my Pi on a regular TV or computer monitor via HDMI, everything performs as expected. When I connected it to a Cisco Spark board via HDMI, I anticipated no change. However after the initial boot instead of the desktop (or specifically a program that is supposed to run after boot), I get a command line (and a kind of oddish looking one, things aren't exactly where they should be, but it's 99% correct looking).

I was able to eventually get it to boot to the desktop by changing the GL option to full in raspi-config, however it's as if it's a secondary desktop. My program that runs full screen at boot isn't visible, and if I try and start it, I get an error that it's already running.

Any idea?